# Changed windows pwd; Can't connect to local sql anymore?

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication

Yesterday I had to change my windows logon password.

Today, when I try to connect to my local instance of Sql Server 2008 R2 through Management Studio, it gives me an error message. 
After reading this ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955470/cannot-connect-anymore-to-local-sql-server-2008-database ), I tried to start up the SQL Server process, but it gives me a logon failure:

[image]

What should I do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check what user account SQL Server is running as. If you set it to e.g. LocalSystem it should work.

Answer (score 2):

In Sql Server Configuration Manager check the account that the Sql services are running as. If you are running it as your account. Update the password or create a new low privileged account for running SQL (best practice). The Localsystem account will work but is not good practice.

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx

Comment: no but it does'n matter much on a local dev machine

Comment: @Rickard True is most cases. However some functions such as backups and agent tasks may work differently/unexpectedly in production with different permissions.